# Lemma: an origin-fixing isometry (distance preserving function) in $\mathbb R^2$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm reading "Abstract Algebra Theory and Applications" by Thomas W. Judson.
I'm at Chapter 12: Matrix Groups and Symmetry.

I've come upon this lemma that an isometry in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fixes the origin is linear.
But I can't understand parts of the proof.

Let $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ be the isometric function.
Knowing that $f(0) = 0$, $|f(\mathbf x)| = |\mathbf x|$ and that $\langle f(\mathbf x), f(\mathbf y)\rangle = \langle \mathbf x, \mathbf y\rangle$ 
with $|\cdot |$  meaning norm and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ meaning inner product.

This is the part that I don't understand:

> Now let $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_2$ be $(1, 0)^t$ and $(0, 1)^t$, respectively. If,
>   $$\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2) = x_1 \mathbf e_1 + x_2 \mathbf e_2. \tag{*}$$
>   Then
>   $$f(\mathbf x) = \langle f(\mathbf x), f(\mathbf e_1)\rangle f(\mathbf e_1) + \langle f(\mathbf x), f(\mathbf e_2)\rangle f(\mathbf e_2) = x_1 f(\mathbf e_1) + x_2 f(\mathbf e_2). \tag{**} $$

Now, how did we jump from $(*)$ to $(**)$?
I know that it's probably simple but I just don't get it.

Comment: $<f(x), f(e_1)> = <x,e_1> = <x_1e_1+x_2e_2, e_1> = <x_1e_1, e_1> + <x_2e_2, e_1> = x_1<e_1,e_1> + x_2<e_1,e_2> = x_1(1) + x_2(0) =x_1$

Comment: A different way to prove this fact would be to notice that an isometry in any metric space takes geodesics (which are straight line in euclidean spaces) to geodesics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express every element $x\in\mathbb R^2$ in terms of an orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2$ as such:
$$
x=\langle x,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle x,e_2\rangle e_2.
$$
Apply this to your current situation. You know that $f(e_1),f(e_2)$ is an basis for $\mathbb R^2$ since $f$ is an isomorphism, and they are orthonormal since $f$ is an isometry, viz.
$$
|f(e_i)|=|e_i|=1\;(\text{for }i=1,2),\quad \langle f(e_1),f(e_2)\rangle=\langle e_1,e_2\rangle =0.
$$

To see $f$ is an isomorphism, suppose $x\neq y$. Then $d(x,y)>0$. Therefore $d(f(x),f(y))>0$, so $f(x)\neq f(y)$, so it is injective. For surjectivity, use a dimension argument between finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: How come f is an isomorphism? That's what missing for me (I understand now how they made the jump) Not so much why f is an isomorphism. (Please understand that I've taken isomorphism only from an abstract algebra viewpoint, not linear algebra)

Comment: Added something, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! Will upvote when I have enough rep.